# C2131 Error for static_assert () in C++

Tags: c++, crtp

Recently I was trying to create a class that can have only one instantiated object. On searching Wikipedia  I found that using the singleton pattern would help out. I didn't like the idea of it and tried to do something of my own. Here is the code for it.

```
#pragma once

#include <list>
#include <functional>

namespace GEvents
{
    struct mouseinfo
    {
    };
    template<typename T>
    struct Counter
    {
        Counter( )
        {
            static_assert( objects_created<2, "Multiple Instances Created" );
            objects_created++;
        }
        static int objects_created;
    };
    template<typename T> int  Counter<T>::objects_created(0);

    class MouseHandler:Counter<MouseHandler>
    {
        std::list<std::function<mouseinfo(void)>> hfunc;
    public:
        void Monitor( )
        {
        }
        void Stop( )
        {
        }
        void operator +=(std::function<mouseinfo(void)> func)
        {
            hfunc.push_back(func);
        }
        void inverseListing( )
        {
            hfunc.reverse( );
        }
        /*size_type & getFunctionCount( )
        {
            return hfunc.size( );
        }
*/


    };

}
```

In the above code I used the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) for solving the issue. What I did was when I created the objects at compile time there would be a static variable that will count the number of objects so created. If it is less than 1 then it's not a problem, but if it goes beyond 1 then the *static_assert* gets false resulting in the printing of the message `Multiple Instances Created`. But when I evaluate this expression the following error results:

```
Error   C2131:  expression did not evaluate to a constant
```

at the line where the static_assert is present. It may be possible that I have misunderstood some concept of object creation. Also what I think is that the static objects are not initialized at compile time, but the space for them is only reserved. If that's the case how can I make the constructor be called at compile time?

Comment: What is not clear to you in the error message?

Comment: I wonder if your singleton pattern will work. What if the objects were created at runtime, do static_asserts still work at runtime?

Comment: I am assuming the objects will only be created at compile time.

Comment: Also please tell me why was I downvoted

Comment: I understood my mistake sorry

Comment: This is hopelessly over-engineered. **Just create one object if you only need one.**

Answer (score 1):

Here, `static_assert` can not satisfy your request. Use `assert` instead.

the *condition* in a `static_assert` **must** be a `literal`, which can promised be checked at **complie time**.

However, your code here seems must to check it at **run time**, so try to use `assert`.

Comment: Yea I just added a comment about this. I don't think the OP's use of static_assert will work at runtime

Comment: @smac89 Yes, use `static_assert` here is meaningless.

Comment: I want to do this at compile time itself.  How is that possible sir

Comment: @GopiKrishnaMenon You can't do this since this should be a variable, not a literal.

Comment: Sir so what is the method of counting objects at compile time in C++

Comment: @GopiKrishnaMenon just like your code, but you should use `assert` macro to check it.

Comment: @GopiKrishnaMenon Sorry, i've misunderstood your question. It's impossible to check it at complie time.